# Find pairs in a List

Tags: c#

So im working on a project in school where I have to write a code that can find pairs of 2, 3, 4 etc... I already know how to find pairs of 2, 3 etc:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
    {
        if (list[i].Efternamn == list[j].Efternamn && i != j)
        {
            textBox4.Text = "A pair was found!";
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox4.Text = "No pairs!";
        }
    }
}
```

but the code is kinda repeating... Is there any other way to find pair of 100 or 200 in an efficient way without many for loops?

Comment: You could sort the list, so all duplicates are next to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Did you study dictionaries or hashtables? You could put each entry in a dictionary as the key, and the count as the value.

Comment: No i sadly have not gotten into dictionaries or hashtables, but I will make sure to learn them. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's cheating in your case but it's easily done with Linq. In this case Linq uses a dictionary internally (most likely).

```
var valuesAndCounts = list
    .GroupBy(x => x)
    .Select(g => new {Value=g.Key, Count=g.Count()})
    .Where(p => p.Count > 1);  // or == 2 or == 100 etc
```